# Loop through array and get objects with a certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

ex:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "grape",
      "color": "purple"
    },
    {
      "name": "apple",
      "color": "green"
    }
  ]
}
```

Let's say I ONLY want to get objects with the `color` of purple. How would I do this?

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? You can use JavaScript's [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const obj = {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "grape",
      "color": "purple"
    },
    {
      "name": "apple",
      "color": "green"
    }
  ]
};

const result = obj.data.filter(element => element.color === 'purple');

console.log(result);
```

This filters through the array and returns a list of objects with the `color` of purple.